# Can some one explain what this code is doing? What will actually happen when Class.create() is invoked?

Tags: javascript, this

How is this below code interpreted? I'm struggling to understand the fact that var F is declared as function and then F.prototype is added as a property to that function. How can one add property to a function or may be I'm reading the code incorrectly. Any help with the explanation or related articles or examples is much appreciated.

```js
var Class={
  create: function(proto){
    var F = function(){
      this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    if (proto) {
      F.prototype = proto;
      if(!F.prototype.initialize){
        throw new Error("Class.create():prototype is missing initialize method");
      }
    }
    return F;
  }
};

Class.create({initialize: function () { alert("Hello World!"); }});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype

Comment: functions in javascript are just **first class objects** meaning they can do anything objects can including have properties defined on them, get passed into other functions etc... Additionally they are invocable.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So, F can be invoked as a function and it can also store the property values, is that so? And this here refers to Class obj?

Comment: Thanks Phil. That link is exactly what I was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

A function in JavaScript is actually an object, and like we assign properties to objects, we can assign properties to functions, no difference here. Additionally when calling a function, if `new` keyword is provided, then the function becomes a class `constructor`, and it creates a new object from the function. Also there is a special default property named `prototype` in every function object, which is responsible for the [inheritence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) in classes.

The code that you have provided, hides the complexity of creating a class, i.e. in Class.create method, it takes prototype object as a parameter, and then internally creates a constructor function (which calls initialize method from the prototype object), and then assigns the prototype object to that function. Furthermore it checks that if the provided prototype object doesn't contain an initialize method, because it's using that method in constructor, an error is thrown. And finally, after all this, the constructor is returned, and what we get is actually a JavaScript class, so using `new` keyword with with will create a new object of that class.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, the default `prototype` method (which is frowned upon, I do believe) with the `object` being passed in the `create` method as your new... "prototype". I've never really seen this done before, but let's look at some examples. Let's say we call the Class like so:

```
var t = Class.create(
  {
    initialize: function() {
      alert('Hello World!');
    },
    test: function(a) {
        alert(a);
    },
    test2: function(a, b) {
        alert(a + ' and ' + b);
    }
  }
);
```

Alright, now `t` is our reference to the class and can be used like so:

```
t.prototype.initialize();
```

Which will pop-up "Hello world!". A little unorthodox, but whatever it works. Now the `F()` function calls the `arguments` dynamically, so if you do:

```
t.prototype.test('Hello');
```

It will just pop-up "Hello" or you can have multiple arguments and use them as you would like:

```
t.prototype.test2('Bacon', 'eggs');
```

When you create the reference to the class, `t`, it is really just calling the function `F()` at its core but unless you define an `initialize()` method within the `object` you pass to the `create` method, it will just error out on you saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined`.

**EDIT**

After reading the other answer, I tried with the `new` keyword and if will, in fact, create the class and call the `initialize` method:

```
var t = new (Class.create({initialize: function() { alert('Hello World!'); }}));
```

You can then handle the reference as a main Object, by calling methods or adding them:

```
// Makes another pop up
t.initialize();
// Create a new method
t.test = function(a){ alert(a); };
// Alerts 'Bacon'
t.test('Bacon');
```

However, be careful, as if you don't include the extra parenthesis around call, you will just end up with what we had before:

```
var t2 = new Class.create({initialize: function() { alert('Hello World!'); }});
t2.prototype.initialize();
```